# Force Ansible to gather facts from group

Tags: postgresql, ansible, ansible-facts

I want to force Ansible to gather facts about hosts inside playbook (to use those data inside role) regardless --limit, but don't know how.

I have playbook like this:

```
- hosts: postgres_access
  tasks:
  - name: Gathering info
    action: setup

- hosts: postgres
  roles:
    - postgres
```

Inside 'postgres' role I have template which iterates over default IPs:

```
{% for host in groups['postgres_access'] %}
host all all {{hostvars[host].ansible_default_ipv4.address}}/32 md5
{% endfor %}
```

This works like magic, but only if I run my playbook without --limit. If I use --limit it breaks, because some hosts in hostgroup have no gathered facts.

```
ansible-playbook -i testing db.yml --limit postgres
```

failed: [pgtest] (item=pg_hba.conf) => {"failed": true, "item": "pg_hba.conf", "msg": "AnsibleUndefinedVariable: 'dict object' has no attribute 'ansible_default_ipv4'"}

How can I have --limit to reconfigure only postgres host, and have network data from other hosts (without doing all other configuration stuff?).

Comment: Have you tried a different approach like tagging your postgres tasks and specifying `--tags postgres`? That way you are not running a limit by inventory groups but by specific tasks

Comment: yes, I think I will use tags. It still would not help with 'configure single host' case (like it often used).

Comment: Made a task for solving this, I put it within the `roles/postgres/tasks/main.yml` file but I bet the location is not relevant if you run it from the playbook instead. See my answer at the bottom.

Answer (score 2):

**Try this please !**

```
- hosts: postgres

  pre_tasks:
  - setup:
    delegate_to: "{{item}}"
    with_items: "{{groups['postgres_access']}}"

  roles:
    - postgres
```

Comment: delegate_to idea is amazing, and it works with 'with_items' as expected (nice trick!). Unfortunately, when 'setup' is delegated, it fills facts for 'postgres' host, not those in postgress_access group.

Comment: oh , if possible please share output ! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can run `setup` for the hosts in the `postgres_access` group as a task and save the facts using `register`:

```
  - name: setup hosts
  action: "setup {{ item }} filter=ansible_default_ipv4"
  with_items: groups.postgres_access
  register: ip_v4

  - name: create template
  template: src=[your template] dest=[your dest file]
```

Just keep in mind that the template needs to change how you are referencing the hosts ipv4 address, I tried with something like this:

```
{% for item in ip_v4.results %}
    host all all {{ item.ansible_facts.ansible_default_ipv4.address }}/32 md5
{% endfor %}
```

For printing just the IP of each host in the group

Comment: Delegate seems to be as well the way to do this from the playbook according to [this](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_delegation.html) however guys went missing the `delegate_facts: True` setting which might be the cause this was not working at all for you.

Comment: I tried `delegate` to no avail. I believe this is pretty much due to the fact that delegate will run tasks in hosts where they are being delegated however, you build the template in a different place and the `hostvars` are not reflected as expected. There are several bugs related to this behavior and I believe you're just hitting another one.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
- hosts: postgres
  pre_tasks:
  - setup:
     delegate_to: postgres_access
  roles:
    - postgres
```

Comment: unfortunately, one can not delegate task to the group.

Answer (score 0):

Use the same role which you have defined as it is with `ignore_errors: true` . So that for hosts which do not have gathered data will not fail.

And if you want data to be gathered for all the hosts in both groups postgres_access and postgres, then add `gather_facts: true` to get facts for postgres group and for postgres_access you already have a task written.

```
- hosts: postgres_access
  tasks:
  - name: Gathering info
    action: setup

- hosts: postgres
  gather_facts: true
  roles:
    - postgres
  ignore_errors: true
```